# Size and asymptotic size of test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study

Consider that we have a sample of $i.i.d$ observations $\{X_{i}\}_{i=1}^{n}$
from a Normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^{2}$.
Suppose we wish to test the null hypothesis that:

$$ H_{0}:\mu=\mu_{0}$$

$$H_{A}:\mu\neq\mu_{0}
 $$

We do not know the variance- this is actualla t-test

$$z=\sqrt{n}\times\frac{\bar{X}-\mu_{0}}{\sigma}$$

This is a two sided test. The question is a homework question. It asks 
"what is the size of the test? What is the asymptotic size of the test? I am not sure as to what the difference between the size of the test and the level of the test is. I thought they were the same thing? In that case, isnt it completely in the experimenter's control? Moreover, why is there an asymptotic consideration (I guess it has to do with the fact that we do not know the variance, but I am not sure how exactly it will affect the test)

Comment: Thanks for adding the self-study tag and explaining why you're stuck - we appreciate it!